# Is sharing an unencrpyted partition from an encrypted linux to an unecrypted windows a good idea?

Tags: windows-7, linux, security, encryption, file-sharing

I have a windows/linux dualboot. My linux partition is encrypted, but I'd like to share a folder to a separate windows computer while linux is running, but I don not want to share any encryption keys.

I can access my unencrypted windows partition from linux, so I should be able to share a folder from there right? Are there any security risks I should be aware of in doing this?

I'm not especially concerned if someone unauthorized is able to read data on my unencrypted shared folder, but I am wondering if there is any kind of security risk to the rest of my machine since linux, samba and so on, are installed on my encrypted partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any real issue doing this, I would how ever make sure you have clamav installed on your linux instance as you may download a file that isn't harmful to your linux installation but that might harm your windows one if shared to it, and as always install an anti-virus on your windows instance (Avast is a good one)